# Python Client-Server Script Unit Testing Error

Tags: python, unit-testing, sockets, python-unittest

I have client and server scripts that serves/reads some data.

When i tried to write unit tests with using PyUnit, there raises a error that i cannot reason it.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    #some set up operations

def testRecieve(self):
    s = socket.socket()   
    s.connect((FEED_SERVER_HOST, FEED_SERVER_PORT))
    sock = socket.socket()    
    #some recieve operations        
    s.close()

 # When i write this code snippet below, i get error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
error. I tried closing 's' socket in tearDown function but still same error raising.

    def testAnotherRecieve(self):
        sock = socket.socket() # Results ERRNO 98.
```

As summary, i cannot create second socket in the unittest class. What may cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [socket docs](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) for [close()](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close), the socket's probably not closed by the time the second test starts up:

> close() releases the resource associated with a connection but does not
>   necessarily close the connection immediately. If you want to close the
>   connection in a timely fashion, call shutdown() before close().